# How to prevent close!-ing before put-ing in onto-chan

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, core.async, transducer

I'd like to run a code like

```
(->> input
     (partition-all 5)
     (map a-side-effect)
     dorun)
```

asynchronously dividing input and output(a-side-effect).

Then I've written the code to experiment below.

```
;; using boot-clj
(set-env! :dependencies '[[org.clojure/core.async "0.2.374"]])
(require '[clojure.core.async :as async :refer [<! <!! >! >!!]])

(let [input (range 18)
      c (async/chan 1 (comp (partition-all 5)
                            (map prn)))]
  (async/onto-chan c input false)
  (async/close! c))
```

explanation for this code:

- Actually elements in input and its quantity is not defined before running and elements in input is able to be taken by some numbers from 0 to 10.
- `async/onto-chan` is used to put a Seq of elements (a fragment of input) into the channel `c` and will be called many times thus the 3rd argument is `false`.
- `prn` is a substitute for `a-side-effect`.

I expected the code above prints

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8 9]
[10 11 12 13 14]
[15 16 17]
```

in REPL however it prints no characters.

And then I add a time to wait, like this

```
(let [c (async/chan 1 (comp (partition-all 5)
                            (map prn)))]
  (async/onto-chan c (range 18) false)
  (Thread/sleep 1000) ;wait
  (async/close! c))
```

This code gave my expected output above.

And then I inspect `core.async/onto-chan`.

And I think what happend:

1. the channel `c` was `core.async/close!`ed in my code.
2. each item of the argument of `core.async/onto-chan` was put(`core.async/>!`) in vain in the `go-loop` in `onto-chan` because the channel `c` was closed.

Are there sure ways to put items before `close!`ing?
write a synchronous version of `onto-chan` not using `go-loop`?

Or is my idea wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is? Why do you create chan `c`, associate a transducer with it, but never take any values from it?

Comment: https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/onto-chan
The onto-chan function returns a channel you can wait for and then close c.

Comment: @gits - my goal is too complex to explain here. I just wrote consise version of my production code. Of course there are many ways if only to print numbers. Just as you said chan `c` isn't token any values, but consumes values with `prn` in itself.

Comment: @megakorre - thanks. The problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example with `Thread.sleep` only ‘works’ by mistake.

The reason it works is that every transformed result value that comes out of `c`’s transducer is `nil`, and since `nil`s are not allowed in channels, an exception is thrown, and no value is put into `c`: this is what allows the producer `onto-chan` to continue putting into the channel and not block waiting. If you paste your second example into the REPL you’ll see four stack traces – one for each partition.

The `nil`s are of course due to mapping over `prn`, which is a side-effecting function that returns `nil` for all inputs.

If I understand your design correctly, your goal is to do something like this:

```clj
(defn go-run! [ch proc]
  (async/go-loop []
    (when-let [value (<! ch)]
      (proc value)
      (recur))))

(let [input (range 18)
      c (async/chan 1 (partition-all 5))]
  (async/onto-chan c input)
  (<!! (go-run! c prn)))
```

- You really do need a producer and a consumer, else your program will block. I’ve introduced a `go-loop` consumer.
- Very generally speaking, `map` and side-effects don’t go together well, so I’ve extracted the side-effecting `prn` into the consumer.
- `onto-chan` cannot be called ‘many times’ (at least in the code shown) so it doesn’t need the `false` argument.

Comment: Thanks, I perhaps understand. But I still have something I cannot understand.
What dose the `<!!` at the last line in the code mean?
Preventing the thread of `go-run!` from being killed before completion of consumption by JVM termination?

Comment: Yes, remember that the code here runs in the main thread, but everything dispatched to the `go` facilities is asynchronous and runs in daemon threads, so you must include some way of synchronising with the `go` threads’ completion. Here `<!!` blocks the main thread (as the very last action) until the channel returned by `go-run!` signals completion.

Answer (score 0):

taking megakorre's idea:

```
(let [c (async/chan 1 (comp (partition-all 5)
                            (map prn)))
      put-ch (async/onto-chan c (range 18) false)]
  (async/alts!! [put-ch])
  (async/close! c))
```

Comment: I’m still confused about the problem you’re trying to solve. When I paste this code into my REPL I get an assertion error: your transducer maps over `prn`, which returns `nil` for each value, and `nil`s cannot be put into or taken from a channel.

Comment: @glts - sorry for my poor explanation. I'd like to run `(->> (range 18) (partition-all 5) (map prn) dorun)` asynchronously. `prn` is a substitute for the side-effect that I actually want to do.

Comment: I didn't notice that `nil`s cannot be put into or taken from a channel. But no assersion error is occured in my environment(clojure 1.7.0 and 1.8.0). As I've wrote transducer associate with a chan returning `nil` likely is bad anyway.

Comment: An exception is occured as you said in a terminal emulator but emacs with cider is not. Maybe this is a difference between you and me.

Comment: The exception does happen whether you see it or not. In Vim, the exception isn’t visible neither (because it happens in a different thread) but it’s still thrown in the background.